# Does Sword Burst target all creatures in range or only enemies?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect, targeting

Does Sword Burst target all creatures in range or only enemies? In 4th edition it only targeted enemies but I don't see any mention of enemies in the 5th edition version (Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide p.143).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## It targets everyone in range

The spell's text reads:

> Each creature within range, other than you

This is intended to be read literally, like most of 5e D&D, so it means that each creature within range (in this case, 5 feet of the caster) is affected by the spell.

The *Sword Burst* cantrip is from the Conjuration school, so unfortunately you can't get around this by using the Sculpt Spells feature from the Evocation wizard.

Comment: Great point on the Sculpt Spell!

Comment: Does anyone above 5 feet of me is targeted too?

Comment: @EASI Yes, it's omnidirectional.

Comment: You can get around it by using Careful Spell, though

Answer (score 8):

## Affects all creatures in range

The spell language states (Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide pp143) :

> Each creature within range[5'], other than you

Without differentiating between hostile/friendly/willing, the default is for *every* creature.